# Action Script 3.0 и ширина / высота клиентской области

Tags: action, actionscript

Добрый день. Возможно ли в AS 3.0 узнать ширину и высоту клиентской области? Если нет, то какие варианты тогда? С помощью JS это сделать легко, но как это передать в мувик? Заранее всем откликнувшимся и заглянувшим спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Возможно ли в AS 3.0 узнать ширину и
> высоту клиентской области?

`stage.stageWidth
stage.stageHeight`

> С помощью JS это сделать легко, но как
> это передать в мувик?

Размеры `stage` зависят от размера контейнера, в котором находится `swf`.

Comment: @p3ps, спасибо. То, что надо. Оказалось все проще, чем я думал.